# Reading then Writing Lines of CSV file - Python3

Tags: python, csv, observable

I have recently written scripts to web scrape and download different files that I need from county property appraiser websites. I now would like to add code that can read the first 2 lines and write them to a new CSV file in order for me to have some observability if any field names are added/deleted/changed. I think I'm pretty close but I've run into an error that I can't seem to figure out. Here is my code:

```
with open('OsceolaTaxParcels09012020.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for i in range(2):
        rows = print(csv_reader.__next__())

    with open('Osceola_Field_Check09152020.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        for i in range(2):
            csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

The error I keep getting is on the last line, **Type Error: writerows() argument must be iterable**.
I figured that the 'rows' variable would be iterable because it contains the first two lines of the original csv file, but alas it is not.

Eventually, I would like to write code to compare two CSV files to each other to easily check for field changes; but that's a whole other can of worms.

Comment: `print` returns `None`, so `rows = None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `writerow`

**Ex:**

```
with open('OsceolaTaxParcels09012020.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('Osceola_Field_Check09152020.csv', 'w', newline="") as new_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
 
    next(csv_reader) # Skip Header
    for _ in range(2):  # Iterate next 2 rows.
        csv_writer.writerow(next(csv_reader))    # Write Row
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you very much! I tried implementing the 'writerow' instead of 'writerows' to my original code. It worked, but it seemed to omit the first row containing the field names and only displayed the first two rows with data. Whereas your code displays the field names row and the first row containing data. Do you know why that is?

Comment: If you need to skip the header add `next(csv_reader)` above the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the `csv` module if you are trying to write the first two lines from one file to another file. You can use `pathlib` for high-level file operations to read from one file and write to another.

```
from pathlib import Path

data = """\
a,b,c
1,2,3
0,0,1
"""

# Write example data to file.
p = Path("data.csv")
p.write_text(data)

# Read contents.
file_contents = p.read_text()
all_lines = file_contents.splitlines()
first_two_lines = all_lines[:2]

# Write to a new file.
output = Path("output.csv")
output.write_text("\n".join(first_two_lines))
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know this was a method. Thank you!